# La vista previa SwiftUI no se corresponde a la emulación

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Os escribo porque estoy intentando crear una app en Swift utilizando SwiftUI con el único propósito de aprender este lenguaje.

Mi intención es: Crear un juego de cartas estilo Memorize.

Lo que estoy intentando es ver cómo verían los usuarios la app desde distintos dispositivos. Sin embargo tengo un problema: La vista previa de SwiftUI no muestra lo mismo que el simulador.

Adjunto imágenes, en rojo se puede ver hasta donde llega la vstack donde s encuentran embebidas el resto de estructuras.

- Vista previa:
  [image: Previsualización de la app en SwiftUI]
- Ejecución:
  [image: Emulación de la app]

Aporto el código por si acaso es útil, aunque no lo creo:

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  DoIt!
//
//  Created by Jesus Mariscal on 20/6/23.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var ViewModel: EmojiMemoryGame
    var body: some View {
        
        
        VStack{
            
            if let thereIsTitle = ViewModel.title {
                Text(thereIsTitle)
                    .padding(.all)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    
                
            } else {
                Text("Seleccione un tema")
                    .padding(.all)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    

                    
              Spacer()
                
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Score  ")
                Text(String(ViewModel.score()))
            }
            .font(.largeTitle)
                
            Spacer()
                if ViewModel.cards.count != 0{
                    
                    ScrollView{
                        LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum:100))]){
                            ForEach (ViewModel.cards){ card in
                                CardView(card: card).aspectRatio(2/3 ,contentMode: . fit)
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        ViewModel.choose(card)
                                    }
                            }
                            
                            
                            
                        }
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        
                        
                    }

                }
                else {
                    Spacer()
                            Text("Seleccione un tema para comenzar")

                        }
                        
                        
                    
            
                
                
            Spacer()
                
            ScrollView(.horizontal){
                                HStack{
                    AnyView(ViewModel.newTheme(firstWord: "Random", secondWord: "Theme", image: "soccerball", info: ["‍♂️","","","","","","","","","‍❄️",""]))
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                    AnyView(ViewModel.newTheme(firstWord: "Nature", secondWord: "Theme", image: "keyboard", info: ["️","","️","⛺️","","️","️","️","️","️",""]))
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                    AnyView(ViewModel.newTheme(firstWord: "Sym", secondWord: "Theme", image: "tree", info: ["","☮️","✝️","☪️","️","☸️","","✡️","","","☯️","☦️","","⛎","♈️"]))
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                    AnyView(ViewModel.newTheme(firstWord: "New", secondWord: "Game", image: "plus", info: []))
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                    

                    
                }
                
            }
            
           
            
            
        }
        .background(Color.red)
        
    }
        
        
        
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
        }
        
        struct CardView: View {
            let card: Memorygame<String>.Card
            var body: some View {
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    ZStack {
                        
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                        if card.isFaceUp {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                                .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 3))
                            Text(card.content).font(Font.system(size: min(geometry.size.width, geometry.size.height) * 0.8))
                            
                        } else {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20).fill()
                            
                        }
                        
                    }
                    .frame(height: geometry.size.height)
                }
                
                
            }
                
        }
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
            static var previews: some View {
                let game = EmojiMemoryGame()
                ContentView(ViewModel: game)
                    .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
                ContentView(ViewModel: game)
                    .preferredColorScheme(.light)
                    
                
            }
        }
```

Comment: Intentaste utilizar .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all) al terminar tu VStack ? Prueba con ello, sino, mete tu VStack dentro de un ZStack y deberia de funcionar